# Some of the users' profile picture are not appearing fully

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-picture

Recently, I saw many, but today I found two

They are

- [Ayesha Hassan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2125893/ayesha-hassan)

[image]

- [judith nisha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1107916/judith-nisha)

[image]

- [Shimon Rachlenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2046306/shimon-rachlenko)
- [This one is on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/163529/shree).

I tried their profile urls in chrome, firefox and safari(I don't have IE), all resulted the same.

By clicking any [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969262/binding-40-sockets-to-40-different-ip-addresses) of their posts, we can see their full profile picture. so, there is no problem with their original image.

Comment: Hmm..all female profiles only :P

Comment: +1 I've had this problem before with images hosted on Imgur (not just avatars and not only on Stack Exchange).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have taken care of reloading this image - there was a change made on IMGURs side to help mitigate these image issues.  This was deployed around the same date that this profile image was uploaded.

If you find others please let me know.

Comment: You did @HugoDozois however that was an image uploaded prior to the image issues.  I have fixed this one up - keep searching and thanks for the report.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2046858 (if you want you can just delete my comment once fixed!)

Comment: found another one http://stackoverflow.com/users/2046306/shimon-rachlenko

Comment: @Azik this time it is male's profile :P

Comment: Now I found one in meta, check [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/163529/shree)

Comment: A [new one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/226839/bathsheba) found on meta, Pl fix.

Comment: I can't see the profile picture of [this answerer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28606353/756941) fully.

Answer (score 3):

Appears to be a bug on imgur's side, possibly to do with imgur applying some stack.imgur specific transform on the image.

Take Ayesha as an example.  The avatar's URL is the following

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjzfO.jpg?s=128&g=1

[image: derp]

If you strip off the `g=1` (I'd guess that means "gravatar=true"?), you get the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjzfO.jpg?s=128

[image: derp]

They apparently aren't really handling the size all that well, either.  Anything other than 128 and it pretty much goes back to the original resolution.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjzfO.jpg?s=256&g=1

[image: derp]

It appears the imgur folks need to fix their stuff.

*Side note,* it only applies to images from i.stack.imgur: [http://i.imgur.com/CUpdrvo.jpg?s=128&g=1](https://i.imgur.com/CUpdrvo.jpg?s=128&g=1)

Comment: Try s=50 - there is a set of predetermined sizes for SE usage.