# Some Users Profile Images not appearing

Tags: support, profile-page, profile-picture, imgur

There are a lot of images not visible to me.

[My Own Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1910920/shaharyar?tab=profile)

[Ian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5666987/ian)

[Alex Jolig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2263683/alex-jolig)

[abramlimpin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284975/abramlimpin)

The issue is actually very weird. The images are appearing on a machine but not on another. Both have different ISPs having different IP addresses.

I know the question has been asked before:

[Why is there a peeking duck in my profile pic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166575/why-is-there-a-peeking-duck-in-my-profile-pic)

[Some of the users' profile picture are not appearing fully](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176257/some-of-the-users-profile-picture-are-not-appearing-fully)

But the answers say that the bug has been fixed.

Comment: Sounds like a problem on your end - if it was server-side, you wouldn't see the pictures from any computer. Try looking at your browser's console for errors.

Comment: @Mat Yes there are errors for every image **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED**. Obviously they will be. But I don't understand the scenario, how can this be a client side error?

Comment: If one of your machines can load the images, then clearly the web servers have them and know how to send them out. So it's an issue on the client or in the middle. That errors show you, or your ISP, or whoever provides DNS for SE, have a DNS issue. Since it is working for some (me, you on some machines), chances are higher it is you or your ISP.

Comment: Well I try to figure out in that case. I can't even see your profile image :)

Comment: It's likely that whatever ISP or network you're using on the computer that can't see them is blocking Imgur, or otherwise preventing you from loading images from their servers. Nothing we can do about it.